# Encountered unsupported property ActionTypeId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

When i create my cloudformation stack for codepipeline, it fails and the error message is "Encountered unsupported property ActionTypeId".

My template is this way:

```
Resources:
  CodePipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref BucketLocation
        Type: S3
      Name: !Ref Name
      RestartExecutionOnUpdate: true
      RoleArn: !Ref RoleAnr
      DisableInboundStageTransitions:
        - Reason: Approve Step
          StageName: Build
      Stages:
        - 
          Name: !Ref StagesName
          Actions:
          - 
            InputArtifacts:
              - 
                Name: CodeCommit  
                ActionTypeId:
                  Category: Source
                  Owner: AWS
                  Version: 1
                  Provider: CodeCommit
            OutputArtifacts:
              -
                Name: sourceartifact
            Configuration:
              BranchName:
                !Ref RepositoryBranch              
              RepositoryName:
                !Ref RepositoryName              
            RunOrder: 1
          -  
            Name: Build
            Actions: 
              - 
                Name: BuildAction
                InputArtifacts:               
                  -
                    Name: CodeBuild 
                ActionTypeId: 
                  Category: Build 
                  Owner: AWS 
                  Version: 1 
                  Provider: CodeBuild
                OutputArtifacts:
                -
                  Name: sourceartifact
                Configuration: 
                  ProjectName: 
                    !Ref ProjectName 
                  RunOrder: 1                
          -
```

I've no idea what the problem might be. I've commented the action type and the stack is still faling.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the YAML indentation so that action properties like ActionTypeId are at the same level.